# How could I make many users working on the same file?

Tags: python, database, pandas

Is it possible in python working on the same file from different users?
Let me be clearer: I would like to make a software that reads a database (I'm using pandas). This software would be used at the same time from different computers and it would read and write the same database. So is there a tool that continuously check what are the last updated voices in the database and refresh it in the RAM of each user? Or there's something much smarter for this purpose?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This (i.e. concurrency) should be handled on the database level.

Comment: What kind of file are we talking about? Is it a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Any [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (in this case the "Isolation" feature is key) compliant databse will give you these features. A good free database for this is PostgreSQL, an alternative (if you have access to it) is an MS-SQL Server.

You really want to use an ACID compliant database for this and don't deal with this yourself.

This problem exists for many decades and has been solved. There are way too many edge cases that will make your life really hard if you want to work with plain files on disk.

Plus, pandas is very capable of reading data from such databses.

## Some Basics

Given the way the question was worded, I am taking the liberty to assume that this may be new territory for you, so here are some "minimal" pointers to get you started. But some things you will *have* to read up on is:

- SQL - Structured Query Language - which is used to fetch data from a database table. You can use this to preprocess and pre-filter data before turning it into a data-frame. This reduces load on your computer and on the network. Depending on the data-size, this reduces the load *considerably*.
- The documentation of the database you are using: Most importantly, what data-types exist, and the installation instructions.

Assuming that you are starting from a CSV file, here is a simple example.

### Preparing the database

You first need to load the CSV data into the database. For the sake of this example I will use PostgreSQL. Other databases will have a different syntax for loading the data.

I will also be *very* liberal with the choice of data-type and I will not use a "primary key". But this is *only* to keep it as simple as possible. You **should** read up on those topics for your final solution!

So, let's assume the following about the DB (See the addendum below on how to run a test instance using docker):

- It runs on host "192.0.2.1" using port "5432"
- The database name (each DB server can run multiple databases) is "stackoverflow"
- The username is "jdoe" with the password "supersecret"

Additionally, let's use a free data-file to play around. Let's use [some AirBNB data](https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data/downloads/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data.zip/3) (which was the first thing that popped up on kaggle at the time of this writing).

We can then use the command-line client `psql` to connect, create a table and load a data-file:

#### Connecting

On the command line, run the following

```
psql postgres://jdoe:supersecret@192.0.2.1:5432/stackoverflow
```

This contains the values listed above. Some can be left out (like password or the default port) but I left them in for illustrative purpose.

You can now run an SQL query to create a new table. This is similar to a data-frame and holds your data for all your users. This query also defines the table name, column names and data-types:

#### Creating the table & loading the data

Obviously, the table only needs to be created once. Data loading depends on your needs. Using SQL each user can also insert, modify and delete data in the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
    id INTEGER,
    name TEXT,
    host_id INTEGER,
    host_name TEXT,
    neighbourhood_group TEXT,
    neighbourhood TEXT,
    latitude FLOAT,
    longitude FLOAT,
    room_type TEXT,
    price INTEGER,
    minimum_nights INTEGER,
    number_of_reviews INTEGER,
    last_review DATE,
    reviews_per_month FLOAT,
    calculated_host_listings_count INTEGER,
    availability_365 INTEGER
);
```

Now we can load the data (from the [kaggle data-set](https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data/downloads/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data.zip/3)):

```
\copy mydata FROM AB_NYC_2019.csv WITH CSV HEADER;
```

See [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html) for details.

After this we can exit the postgres console and go back into Python/Pandas.

#### Pandas

First, make sure you have a Python library able to connect to postgres like `psycopg2-binary`.

Imports:

```
import pandas
import psycopg2
```

Connectiong and reading:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://jdoe:supersecret@192.0.2.1/stackoverflow")
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mydata", connection, index_col="id")
```

## Addendum - Running postgres in docker

A new docker instance can be started using the following command:

```
docker run \
    --rm \
    --name pg-docker \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres
```

This will create a database with the name `postgres` which can be accessed by the user `postgres` and the password `docker`. These values can be used for the example above, and should of course not be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

check this one, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html 
pandas with SQL will be a good solution

Comment: That link is broken